# MUI Autocomplete label is not updated when options are updated

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, internationalization

I have a multilingual website and an Autocomplete that lists translatable labels. Whenever the language is changed, it's container fetches its options with the same IDs, but translated labels.

The problem is, although the options in the dropdown are indeed translated, the current value, itself, is not:

[image: dropdown and labels in different languages]

How do I make the Autocomplete update its value (or trigger the onChange manually) when the options are changed?

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-mui-v5-forked-i3899e?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I was about posting this same question. I update the option list that actually change in the list but the selected option inside the input stays with the old data. Did you get to solve it? If so, please share the solution.